# How to make the height of the div take all the space?

Tags: css, navigation, twitter-bootstrap, uinavigationbar

Here is my css rule together with the markup:

```
<div style = "height:100%;">
<div style = "width:220px; margin-left: 200px;font-size:16px; height:auto;">
    <div class='navbar-inner'>
        <div class='container'>
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <div>   
            <li <?php if($page == 'upload_track'){ echo "class = \"active\""; }?>><a href = "#">Upload a new Track</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">View all blog post</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">View all tracks uploaded</a></li>
        </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style = "width:220px; margin-left: 200px;font-size:16px; height:auto;">
```

as of now I am making them an inline style so that it would be easy for me to change them. since switching texteditors is kind of a hassle for me.

How would I make that div take up all the available height? like the very bottom of the page. as of now it looks something like this
[image]

what I wanted to see is that the black div takes up all the available height in the page

Comment: Did you read the whole question?

Comment: My little knowledge concludes from given article:  Height of all parents should be 100% also height of child should be 100% because by default height is "auto" of any element.
http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it can be done. Check out [this example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mKPcE/).

Basically I changed your HTML to this:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div class='navbar-inner'>
        <div class='container'>
            <ul class="nav nav-list">
                <div>   
                    <li><a href = "#">Upload a new Track</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">View all blog post</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">View all tracks uploaded</a></li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Essentially all I did was remove the outermost div (the one with only the `style="height: 100%"` on it) and gave the next div an id.

The CSS is as follows:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

#navbar { 
    /* this was moved from being an inline style in the div: */
    width:220px; margin-left: 200px;font-size:16px;
    height: 100%;
}​
```

Basically, in order for the navbar strip to use up 100% of the height, you need to make sure that the html and body actually *take* up 100% of the available height. (That is, 100% on `#navbar` is 100% of the height of the parent element; if the parent element isn't the height of the browser, then it doesn't work.)
​