# Why my children div can't take all the height of the parent div?

Tags: html, css, meteor, menu

Following this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170494/how-to-make-the-height-of-the-div-take-all-the-space) who is exactly the same as mine  I tried to make my `menu_gauche` taking all the height.

So when I look into the CSS with the navigator:

```
body {
    color: #73879C;
    background: white;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Roboto, Arial, "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.471;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I can see my `body`who take 100% as the answer of the question linked.

Then I look into my child `menu_gauche`:

```
#menu_gauche {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

The value is 100% so it should work right ?

But for an unknown reason the `menu_gauche` isn't taking all the height of the parent.

Someone has an idea what could make this happens ?
My html look like this:

```
<body>
<div class="container body">
    <div class="main_container">

      <div id="menu_gauche" class="col-md-3 left_col">
            <div class="left_col scroll-view">
                <div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
                    <a id="logoBoat" class="site_title" href="/"><i class="fa fa-ship"></i> <span>Control Docker!</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>


                <!-- menu profile quick info -->
                <div class="profile clearfix">
                </div>
                <!-- /menu profile quick info -->

                <br/>

                <!-- sidebar menu -->
                <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
                    <div class="menu_section">
                        <!-- {{> loginButtons}} -->
                        <ul class="nav side-menu">
                            <li><a><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Docker machines <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
```

Here a picture of the result, the part in red is the menu, the part in black the footer and we can see the body in white. The grey part is a panel that is upside the body so don't worry about it :
[image]

Comment: can you provide a JSfiddle?

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw it will be hard but let me try

Comment: Jerome don't worry if you can't. it's all good.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw it's really hard because I use Meteor + FontAwesome

Comment: Jerome, can you update you post with the  full HTML, so I can test it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139772/discussion-between-jerome-and-ousmane-mahy-diaw).

Comment: Have you also applied `height: 100%` on `html`?

Comment: @ghybs yes I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys finally I founded ! I needed to modify a bit the CSS like this (main point is adding `position:fixed`)

```
.nav-md .container.body .col-md-3.left_col {
    width: 230px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    background-image: url(/navBar.jpg);
    color: #001155;
    height: 100% !important;

}

.nav-sm .container.body .col-md-3.left_col {
    width: 70px;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    background-image: url(/navBar.jpg);
    color: #001155;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

both [div class="container body"] & [div class="main_container"] need 100% height as well, because they are the parent elements for menu_gauche.

try adding this:

```
div.container, div.main_container {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: that's odd. there may be something in the existing  classes preventing it from working. i made a couple changes if you want to try again.

Comment: Now they have the setting `height:100%` but the white block is still here, look the pic in the edit

Comment: I would look into the css for 'col-md-3' & 'left_col', as well as 'main_container' & 'container'. if any of those set the div to act as a span(inline-block), it won't use the height attribute.

use firebug/dev tools if you're not already to really inspect the divs and see which one is not reaching 100% height. is it actually the menu or is it the parent divs? give every div a different border/background color to differentiate if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you are ignoring the `<html>` area to be `height: 100%`. The `<body>` is wrapped inside the `<html>` area(we ignore it mostly, but it's there).

And therefore, even if you give the `<body>` 100% height, it won't cover the entire height because the `<html>` is not set to `height: 100%;`.

So, to solve the issue, set `<html>`'s height to 100%.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```